# Creating a ROS msg

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, package.xml, cmake, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the steps of the tutorial "Creating a ROS msg and srv"
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv
and the step 3 I got this message:

```
Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [unit8] in package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [['/home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg', '/home/spyros/catkin_ws/devel/share/beginner_tutorials/msg']]
```

At the step 2.1  how can I know if these two lines are uncommented ? Do I have to open the package.xml file with the editor as I did with the CMakeLists.txt?
After I finish editing the CMakeLists.txt file, do I have to save it with the same name?

I followed the similar steps for Creating a srv and the result in step 4.2 was correct.

I am using ROS kinetic.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292867/creating-a-ros-msg/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-31**:\

> step 3 didn't work normally

What does this mean? What happened, what errors did you get? Please update your question with this information.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-06-01**:
I updated my question with the message I got. I tried again with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> At the step 2.1 how can I know if these two lines are uncommented ? Do I have to open the package.xml file with the editor as I did with the CMakeLists.txt?

Yes, you have to open the `xml` file using any text editor and uncomment those lines. Usually for `xml` files, comments are between `<!--`  and `-->`. So, just make sure that is not the case.

> After I finish editing the CMakeLists.txt file, do I have to save it with the same name?

Yes, that is necessary as it enables you to run `catkin_make` correctly (without errors).

> Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [unit8] in package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [['/home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg', '/home/spyros/catkin_ws/devel/share/beginner_tutorials/msg']]

This error can be solved by correcting `unit8` to `uint8`.

---

Originally posted by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) with karma: 18 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-06-01**:
I tried the tutorial again and I have the same problem. At the step 3 I got the message:

Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [unit8] in package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [['/home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg', '/home/spyros/catkin_ws/devel/share/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-01**:
`unit8` is not a message type, so that error is understandable. Should it be `uint8`? And that is not a message, but a primitive type.

**Comment by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) on 2018-06-01**:
Yes, it should be `uint8`.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2018-06-01**:
Yes. That was my mistake. I changed it to uint8 and I got the correct result in the command
rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num

Thank you!

**Comment by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) on 2018-06-01**:
I have updated the answer. If this answer is correct, then click the green tick so that this question is answered and can be closed.